# How to Dynamically flip an Action in Blender?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I am creating a walk cycle and I am really tired of manually flipping the animation from side to side whenever I make changes to the walk cycle.

Is there a way to only create a left side action for the walk cycle and have blender dynamically flip the action? It is like having an animation modifier the input is the action and the output is the flipped action.

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: there is no need for an example blend file, this question isn't tied to a specific Scenario it is a general question, I am looking for a dynamic way to flip an action, For example let 's say I have `action.left` and I Flipped this action using `paste X-flipped Pose` to create `action.right`. now if I made a change to `action.Left` I have to go again and use `paste X-flipped Pose` in order to get `action.right`, so what I want is a way to have `action.right` be calculated dynamically using `action.left`.

Comment: If you don't have a blend file might I suggest posting an example images showing what you want.